# OPensuse does not reboot after installing I install gnutls

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, opensuse, gnutls

I am trying to build ffmpeg on OpenSuse with the following flags:

```
ffmpeg-3.4.8 # ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --extra-cflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g' --optflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g' --disable-htmlpages --enable-pic --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-gpl --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid
```

I get the forrowing error:

```
ERROR: gnutls not found using pkg-config

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

I then install gnutls from this link:
https://software.opensuse.org/package/gnutls

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Leap:15.2:Update/standard/openSUSE:Leap:15.2:Update.repo

zypper refresh
zypper install gnutls
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides 'this-is-only-for-build-envs' needed by the to be installed libunbound-devel-mini-1.6.8-lp152.9.3.1.x86_64
Solution 1: do not install gnutls-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64
Solution 2: break libunbound-devel-mini-1.6.8-lp152.9.3.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c/d/?] (c): 2
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
 gnutls libgnutls-dane0 libopts25 libunbound-devel-mini

The following package requires a system reboot:
gnutls

4 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 1.1 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 4.0 MiB will be used.

Note: System reboot required.
Continue? [y/n/v/...? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving package libopts25-5.18.12-lp152.4.3.1.x86_64                                                                                     
(1/4),  65.6 KiB (134.5 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libopts25-5.18.12-lp152.4.3.1.x86_64.rpm ......................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving package libunbound-devel-mini-1.6.8-lp152.9.3.1.x86_64                                                                           (2/4), 331.5 KiB (723.4 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libunbound-devel-mini-1.6.8-lp152.9.3.1.x86_64.rpm ............................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving package libgnutls-dane0-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64                                                                                (3/4),  91.7 KiB ( 34.6 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libgnutls-dane0-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64.rpm .................................................................................................................[done]
Retrieving package gnutls-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64                                                                                         (4/4), 675.4 KiB (  3.1 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: gnutls-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64.rpm ..............................................................................................................[done (3.6 MiB/s)]

Checking for file conflicts: ..............................................................................................................................................[done]
(1/4) Installing: libopts25-5.18.12-lp152.4.3.1.x86_64 ....................................................................................................................[done]
(2/4) Installing: libunbound-devel-mini-1.6.8-lp152.9.3.1.x86_64 ..........................................................................................................[done]
(3/4) Installing: libgnutls-dane0-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64 ...............................................................................................................[done]
(4/4) Installing: gnutls-3.6.7-lp152.9.12.1.x86_64 ........................................................................................................................[done]
```

Note the system reboot hint.
When I reboot my system I it just boots to a black screen.  It does not display the logon prompt.
Any ideas as to why this is or how I can debug it?

Comment: »» gnutls not found «« means you will have to install gnutls-devel: `# zypper in gnutls-devel` ........ The system `gnutls` is always installed already at OS install. ........ An alien version of gnutls "kills the OS". ......... Possible repair method : Extract / reinstall the system version from an external live OS .

Comment: Please always do a search before installing an alien version : `zypper se gnutls` . ....... And check what you have installed : 1. `rpm -qa gnutls` .... 2.  `rpm -qa | grep [package name]` (or part of name). ....... 3. `rpm -qa --last > last-packages.txt` ......... 4. `rpm -qa | sort > alphabetic-list.txt`